# OSGi Diagnose Component's Missing Dependency

Tags: osgi

During development, we tend to break up our declarative service components, so OSGi naturally do not activate other dependent components. Is there a way to diagnose the underlying problem, ie. "why the component is not activated?"

For a simple dependency graph:

```
A------>B------>C------->E
                ^
                |
        D-------+
```

When `E` fails to be activated all dependent components, `C`, `D`, `B`, `A` don't get activated as well. I need a console command to ask "why `A` is not activated?" and the answer would contain the answer, "A depends on B, B depends on C, C depends on E, and E is not available".

Comment: probably no. If E is not active, then its dependents cannot be activated. This gets even more clear, when I tried to manually activate a component (say B), but logs said that because E is not resolved, you cannot activate B. So, you need to activate E first.

Answer (score 2):

This does not exist currently, though it could be developed using the `ScrService` API. This would certainly make an interesting and useful project.

Your two diagnostic options are the moment are:

1. The `scr:list` and `scr:info` commands in the gogo shell. These will tell you why an individual component is not active. For example if you ask why A is not active, it will tell you that it has an unsatisfied reference for the `B` service. You would then have to trace down which component is supposed to register the `B` service and work out why that is not active. And so on.
2. The [X-Ray plugin for Felix WebConsole](http://softwaresimplexity.blogspot.com/2012/05/x-rays-for-osgi.html) will give you a graphical representation of services and components. It won't directly give you the root cause as you asked for, but it may help an experienced user to trace down the problem more quickly than the `scr` commands.

Comment: If you need a working example, in the Apache Felix Dependency Manager we have implemented a shell command that does exactly this. It uses an internal API to do the heavy lifting. I'm not suggestion you should ditch DS but rather that you could use that code as an example when doing as Neil suggests (implement such logic yourself). For reference it is the "dm wtf" command (an acronym that we all know stands for "where's the failure" ;) ).

Comment: Thanks Marcel. The main problem with building this kind of diagnostic is that components don't depend on components. A component depends on a *service*, which might or might not be provided by another component. So any solution you build will have to use a certain amount of guessing and heuristics. It will still be useful, just not perfect.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, if you are using equinox (as I am), the respective commands are "list" and "comp". Commands are implemented in this file: [SCRCommandProvider.java](http://bit.ly/1MTuGJ6)

Comment: We have solved that, because we not only model components but also dependencies (including service dependencies, but also things like configuration dependencies). We also know what services a component exposes if it would have resolved. Now of course you can make highly dynamic scenarios that will defeat our algorithm but in practice in big projects it works very well for us.

Comment: @MarcelOffermans Sure, and of course you can work out the services a DS component should provide, as long as they are using the simple `<provide>` element. But anybody could provide a service programmatically, or with a different component model etc.